# Using both discrete and continuous moves in Metropolis-Hastings

Tags: markov-process, continuous-data, metropolis-hastings

I want to sample a continuous distribution $f$ using the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. Can I define my transition kernel as being sometimes discrete and sometimes continuous as long as I use the correct acceptance probability? I'm trying to make sense of continuous-state Markov chain theory so I apologize if I'm being confusing.

For example, suppose $f$ is a standard normal distribution. Now suppose that 1) with probability $r$ I perform a random walk with a standard normal kernel $q$ and 2) with probability $1-r$ I perform $x\mapsto -x$. The acceptance probability for 1) would be
$$
\alpha(x, y) = \min\left(1,\ \frac{f(y)rq(y, x)}{f(x)rq(x, y)} \right),
$$
where $y$ is the proposal, and the acceptance probability for 2) would be
$$
\alpha(x, -x) = \min\left(1, \frac{f(-x)(1-r)}{f(x)(1-r)} \right).
$$

1. How to properly define this Markov chain's transition probabilities (e.g. Can I use a Dirac measure for $x\mapsto -x$? Can I work with densities or in order to mix Lebesgue and discrete measures I should work directly with the transition kernel measure? In that case, what would the detailed balanced equation look like?)
2. Is it ok that $q$ could *technically* (in a numerical simulation) propose $x\mapsto -x$? Normally, each move which result in the proposal should be summed in the acceptance probability. In that case however, I'm thinking that $-x$ has measure $0$ and both moves have essentially "disjoint proposal sets".
3. Is this a valid Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, meaning that the stationary distribution is $f$?

I feel like it should work as long as the continuous part of the proposal makes the chain irreducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is theoretically valid to

1. combine sequentially or randomly several Markov kernels that all preserve the stationary distribution $f$
2. use Markov kernels that operate on subspaces of lower dimensions, hence with different dominating measures, provided the resulting combination of kernels is irreducible.

An illustration of 1. and 2. is the Gibbs sampler, since it combines Markov kernels, all operating on a subspace.

The easiest way to envision your proposal is thus as a combination of two Markov kernels, the random walk kernel and the sign flip kernel. The latter is operating on the "sign" subspace, with an acceptance probability indeed equal to $f(-x)\big/ f(x)\wedge 1$. Because each kernel is stationary wrt $f$, there is no need to involve the mixture in the acceptance probability and $r$ does not appear in the acceptance probabilities (although it impacts the efficiency of the algorithm).

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! What does the transition kernel look like when combining kernel of different subspaces? Is it something like this?
$$
P(x, A) = r \int_{y\in A} q(x, y) dy + (1-r) \delta_{-x}(A)
$$

Comment: The Markov kernel also includes the acceptance step(s)!

Comment: Oops you are right! Otherwise it's correct?

Comment: This could be correct (with the inclusion of the Dirac mass at $x$).

Comment: For future reference, since it seems like I cannot edit my comment, here is the corrected (?) transition kernel
\begin{align*}
P(x, A) &= r\int_{y\in A} \alpha(x, y)q(x, y) dy + (1-r) \alpha(x, -x) \delta_{-x}(A) \\
        &\hspace{6pt}+ \bigg(1 - r\int_{y\in \mathbb{R}} \alpha(x, y)q(x, y) dy - (1-r)\alpha(x, -x) \bigg)\delta_x(A).
\end{align*}